# Autopopulate Text Field with a Date Value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am developing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM. I wrote some javascript code to autopopulate a text field with the year portion of a date field. I will admit that I am still a novice at javascript development so my code may not be well written. While the code works and the year is ultimately populated, it initially flashes "1969" for a split second then it disappears. I have to press the save button twice before the correct year is displayed. I prefer that the 1969 not be displayed at any point and also to be able to populate the field as soon as the user hits the save button. Please advise. Thank you!

```
var dateString = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('finalizeddate').getValue();
var finalDate = new Date(dateString);
var finalYear = finalDate.getFullYear();
var str = finalYear.toString();
var revisionStatus = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('revisionstatus');

// If status is final, then populate quota year with finalized date year. 
// Otherwise, do not set a value
if (revisionStatus.getSelectedOption().value == final) {
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute('quotayear').setValue(str);
} else { 
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute('quotayear').setValue();
}
```

Comment: What is `final`?

Comment: That should work if you run it `OnSave`

Comment: Is "1969" a default value for that field?

Comment: @JamesWood Final is a database value. I didn't add that portion to the code pasted above

Comment: @Alex I am running the code as an onSave event but it was not working as desired

Comment: @DenLun When I change the drop-down value for Revision Status to Final, the Quota Year field flashes the value 1969 for a second then disappears. When I am finished filling out the form and I click on the Save button twice, 2017 is displayed (which is the expected value)

Answer (score 0):

As James Wood noted in his comment

> What is Final?

`Final` is a reserved word in JavaScript (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) and since this is the value of an optionset should be wrapped in quotes.

Also, in the version of the SDK I have, it says that `getValue()` on an optionset field returns the number **value** not the label **text** of the option, so you may need to check your customisations to find the correct value for the `final` option.

Once you have that can you try the following code and see if it works?

```
var revisionStatus = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('revisionstatus');
var finalOption = '1';      // this is the value of the optionset, not the label

// If status is 'final', then populate quota year with finalized date year.
if (revisionStatus.getSelectedOption().value == finalOption)
{
    var finalizedDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('finalizeddate').getValue();
    var year = new Date(finalizedDate).getFullYear().toString();
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('quotayear').setValue(year);
}
// Otherwise, do not set a value
else
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('quotayear').setValue();
}
```

Also, as a side note, I assume that these are not your actual schema names because they don't have your developer prefix?